# MongoDB find() query to Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following MongoDB command I would like to execute in Java to return a dataSet:

`db.temp_measurements.find({$expr: {$gt: [{$dateFromString: {dateString: "$Time",format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L",timezone: "UTC"}},ISODate("2023-05-01T00:00:00Z")]}})`

This command returns all entries which have the 'Time' field greater than the 1st of may 2023. It is done this way because the dates follow a format that isn't recognized as an ISODate by MongoDB (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS), so this is the way I have found to be able to correctly get the results I want.

However, I can't seem to be able to execute this query from Java.

I have tried these commands ('dbo' is a BasicDBObject):

`dbo.append("{$expr:", "{$gt: [{$dateFromString: {dateString: '$Time',format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L',timezone: 'UTC'}},ISODate('2023-05-01T00:00:00Z')]}}");`

`dbo.append("$Time:", "{$expr:", "{$gt: [{$dateFromString: {dateString: '$Time',format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L',timezone: 'UTC'}},ISODate('2023-05-01T00:00:00Z')]}}"`

I have also tried some strange commands that ChatGPT suggested, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!